# angled column header and width

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

Please see the rmd file below. I'd like to angle some column headers and have widths be respected.

In the first table without row_spec() the widths are respected but when row_spec() is added to angle a few column headers the widths no longer hold. Any idea how to angle and have the widths remain?

rmd file

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(kableExtra)
```

```{r table1,  echo= FALSE, comment = FALSE, message= FALSE, warning = FALSE,results='asis'} 

dt <- mtcars[1:5, 1:6]
rownames(dt) = NULL
colnames(dt)= c("long col 1","long col 12","long col 13","long col 14","long col 15","long col 16")

  kable(
      dt, 
      format ="latex",
      caption = "No angle",
      booktabs = T,
      longtable = T,
      escape = F,
      align = "c",
      linesep=""
      ) %>%
     kable_styling(latex_options = c("repeat_header" ), font_size=8)%>% 
     collapse_rows(columns = 1, latex_hline = "major", valign = "middle")  %>%
    column_spec(c(1,2,3,4,5,6), width = c("8em","5em","6em","3em","3em","3em"  ) )


```

```{r table2,  echo= FALSE, comment = FALSE, message= FALSE, warning = FALSE,results='asis'} 


  kable(
      dt, 
      format ="latex",
      caption = "With Angled columns",
      booktabs = T,
      longtable = T,
      escape = F,
      align = "c",
      linesep=""
      ) %>%
     kable_styling(latex_options = c("repeat_header" ), font_size=8)%>% 
     collapse_rows(columns = 1, latex_hline = "major", valign = "middle")  %>%
     row_spec(0, angle =   c(rep(0,2),rep(90,2),rep(0,2)  )  )%>%
    column_spec(c(1,2,3,4,5,6), width = c("8em","5em","6em","3em","3em","3em"  ) )


```
````